# G751JY AC charger disconnects while gaming.

Tags: power-supply, power, gpu

So a few months ago my battery died, which in turn made my computer turn off while gaming. It seemed that the computer (GPU?) needed more power than the AC could give causing it to shut down.

So I got a new battery, and everything worked fine for a week or two. Now when I play demanding games like PUBG the AC charger disconnects and reconnects frequently, and sometimes the computer shuts down. GPU-Z logs say that the temperature is not above 80' degrees just before the shut downs, which leads me to believe its a problem with energy consumption.

The computer is an ASUS ROG G751JY with Nvidia 980m. The AC part is original, and the seller said the battery is original too (and it looks identical to the original).

Other things to note is that during gaming the right side of the laptop is significantly warmer than the left side. The right side is where the AC intake is. The AC jack (?) is also pretty warm when gaming.

Again the disconnections and shut-downs only happens during demanding games. Never during browsing. Stress tests with FurMark will sometimes shut my computer off immediately, other times just disconnects and reconnects of the AC charger.

I am attaching some photos from a gaming session, with information form HWiNFO64 and GPU-z. The last picture is taken just as the charger disconnects and reconnects.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR0cz.jpg

If I understand correctly my AC charger has 220 watt (19,5 V x 11,8 A), so I don't understand why its disconnecting. I thought maybe I could try to undervolt the GPU, but I dint find a program that could do it. The volt option in Afterburner is already at minimum it seems. I can only overvolt?

Regards

Comment: I would suggest you replace your power supply. Your computer should be fully capable of running without your battery when connected to power. That is the real issue here.

Comment: Yeah. I am starting to come to this conclusion too. But how unlucky am I? A dead batery AND a faulty AC charger in two months.

Comment: Batteries age out. That's normal. It also sound as though you bought the laptop used, and there's no way to tell what damage or abuse was concealed by the seller. Further, luck had nothing to do with this: sometimes parts just fail. And finally, it's possible a faulty power supply contributed to the failed battery.

Comment: Thanks alot @music2myear - you are probably 100% right. When I run Furmark now, every time the laptop shuts down immediately when starting the stress-test. So its definitely not a problem with heat, and probably a faulty PSU problem. You think there is a way for me to fix it myself or should I just buy a new one. 

Question: if I test the PSU on one of those measuring things, should I get the Volt, Ampere or Watt? :)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for a computer to heat up when it is being run, and it is normal for the heat to be greater at different parts of the laptop.

Based on your description of the problem, I'd guess that you had a bad power supply when you bought this computer used, and this bad power supply contributed to the failure of your battery.

Your computer should be fully capable of running without a batter at all. The power supply should be fully capable of running the computer all by itself. The fact this is not the case is the primary evidence for the power supply itself being the root problem.

Replacing the power supply isn't terribly expensive. A generic power supply with the correct necessary output will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks alot for your thorough reply. I will search for a generic power supply to see if that helps.

Comment: I still wonder though, why the computer shuts off, even though I have a functioning battery? It seems like when there is too much demands the AC charger disconnects and sometimes the battery cant even keep the laptop on - which in turn makes the laptop shut down

Comment: Power issues can have odd and seemingly illogical symptoms. The biggest problem is that power issues tend to cause further damage to the rest of the system as well. It is critical that you do not run the computer on these faulty power sources any longer than absolutely necessary to minimize the chance of damage to other components.

Comment: One more thought. I just tested fumark with only the battery, and the laptop shut down after 2 seconds. So how can the PSU be the problem when the same thing happens with just the battery? 

I wish I found a way to undervolt the GPU.